# jQuery() not finding elements in jQuery.parseHTML() result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing tests with QUnit and using `$.ajax()` to pull in HTML for some of the tests from the the dev site running on my local:

```
add_elements = function(location, selector) { 
  $.ajax(location, {async: false}).done(function(data) {
    stor.$els = $(selector, $.parseHTML(data));
    stor.$els.appendTo($('body'));
  })
}
```

Using this function at a certain location, I get the following `data` passed to my `.done()` callback:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<div id="app-container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <small>Text</small>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="hero-units" class="carousel-inner slide">

        <div class="hero-unit home item active">
            <h1>
                Text text text
            </h1>
            <p>
                More text!
            </p>
            <div id="app-nav">
                <a id="lets-go" class="btn btn-primary btn-large nav-forward" href="/what-up/">
                    Let's go
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/site-fiddle.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/site.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works if `selector` is `#hero-units` or `.hero-unit`, but `$(selector, $.parseHTML(data))` returns nothing if `selector` is `#app-container`! And I want a `jQuery` object for the `div#app-container` element.

And here is what kills me:

- `$.parseHTML(data)` **does** contain the `div#app-container` element. It's just `$.parseHTML(data)[7]`.
- Yet, `$('#app-container', $.parseHTML(data))` is an empty array.
- `$('div', $.parseHTML(data))` includes all the `div`s inside of `div#app-container`, but not `div#app-container` itself.

What's going on here? It appears that what's happening is that `$` is not looking at any of the top-level elements returned by `$.parseHTML(data)` or `$($.parseHTML(data)))`, and just their children.

How can I get a `jQuery` object for `div#app-container` from this `$.parseHTML(data)`?

***ANSWER***

The `$(selector, $.parseHTML(data))`-style lookup uses `$.find`. Since I'm looking for an element that's top-level in this jQuery object, I should use `$.filter` instead. Voila.

Comment: thanks for your update with `filter` much nicer than the answer below. although that would also have worked :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$.filter` working to get the outermost node of the output from `$.parseHTML`? How do you pass the output of parseHTML to `$.filter` ? It only accepts one argument.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to create a DOM element to append the results of `.parseHTML()` first so that it creates a DOM tree before jQuery can traverse it and find `div#app-container`.

```
var tempDom = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(str));
var appContainer = $('#app-container', tempDom);
```

I used your example and got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/gEYgZ/

The `.parseHTML()` function seems to choke on the `<script>` tags, so I had to remove them.

*PS.* Obviously `<output>` is not a real HTML tag, just using it for the example

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It needs to be appended inside of something _first_, and then searched. jQuery isn't finding top-level tags in this case. I wonder why.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I was thinking of making one. Should have done that before posting.

Comment: @dimadima It's not about top-level tags, the result of `$.parseHTML(str)` is not a DOM element yet. It's kind of in a purgatory state, if you will, and needs to be brought into the DOM world. Either by `.append()`, `.html()`, etc.

Comment: really? i would have thought wrapping it in `$()` would be sufficient. like, from http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/: If a string is known to be HTML but may start with arbitrary text that is not an HTML tag, pass it to `jQuery.parseHTML()` which will return an array of DOM nodes representing the markup. A jQuery collection can be created from this, for example: `$($.parseHTML(htmlString))`. This would be considered best practice when processing HTML templates for example."

Comment: @dimadima Maybe bring this up with the folks at jQuery :P

Comment: maybe, right? but i think this must be something of a purgatory, something of a design decision. i think the issue is that there's no way to specify that the `.find` context should be inclusive

Comment: @dimadima I would have to say the `$()` function is already very complex as it is, it can handle so many types of arguments. I'd understand why they didn't want to over complicate it.

Comment: yeah, i agree. i just didn't know about this behavior, if i'm understanding it correctly

Comment: What does $('#container', tempdo); does? I thought you have to this: $('#container').html( tempdo.html() )

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
$($.parseHTML('<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>')).find('#foo');
```

for strings that start with `<` you can shorter that code to just:

```
$('<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>').find('#foo');
```

Comment: Ah, right, but what about `$($.parseHTML('<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>')).find('div')`? Yields an empty array. Anyway, the `.find()` approach above is the same as `$('#foo', $($.parseHTML('<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>')))`

Comment: @dimadima it return element for me, I tested before I post the answer.

Comment: @dimadima it wont find div because it the root of the html if you want to find div then just use `$($.parseHTML('<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>'))` and you got div.

Comment: Works. Notice the double $

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this.

Turns out `$.parseHTML` returns a vanilla `Array` of DOM elements, and that doesn't support the jQuery find that you want.

I think this is the cleanest solution for converting an HTML string to a jQuery object:

```
var html = '<div><span id="foo">hello</span></div>';
var $foo = $(html).find('#foo');
```

*Note: You may want to use `$.trim` around your html strings so jQuery doesn't get confused by whitespaces.*

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have anything to do with the html not being part of the DOM. It's just that for whatever reason the top level tag(s) in the parsed HTML cannot be found.  If the element you are looking for is wrapped in another tag, then the find works as you expect.  BTW, wrapping the element in the body tag won't work, but all the others I have tried work fine.

```
var bad = $.parseHTML('<ul><<li><one/li>/<li>two</li></ul>');
console.log($(bad).find('li').length);  //will be 2
console.log($(bad).find('ul').length);  //will be 0 

var good = $.parseHTML('<div><ul><<li><one/li>/<li>two</li></ul></div>');
console.log($(good).find('li').length); //will be 2
console.log($(good).find('ul').length); //will be 1
```

This is definitely the case in jQuery 1.11, not sure what happens in later versions. Here is a fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/ndnnhf94/

Answer (score 2):

Above answers didn't work for me, this did:

use jQuery.parseHTML to parse the HTML into an array of elements; then you’ll be able to **convert it to a jQuery collection** and **use filter** to restrict the collection to elements matching a selector.

```
var html =
'<td class="test">asd</td>' +
'<td class="last">jkl</td>';
var obj = $($.parseHTML(html)).filter('.test');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try with this:

```
$('body', $.parseHTML(data))
```

Comment: That's not related to my problem. My problem is that `div#app-container` is not being found by jQuery. I appreciate your time, but if you have more time, please re-read the question.

Comment: Umm...it just a suggestion try with this.

Comment: That is also an empty array.

Comment: What's happening is that `$` is not looking at any of the top-level elements returned by `$.parseHTML(data)` or `$($.parseHTML(data)))`, and just their children.

Comment: why not create a elem with that `id` and append in that one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work, especially if you specifically need to find the element by id;

```
function findInParsed(html, selector){
    return $(selector, html).get(0) || $(html).filter(selector).get(0);
}
```

If you need the jquery version of the object then you can get it with this

```
function findInParsed(html, selector){
    var check = $(selector, html).get(0);
    if(check)
        return $(check);
    check = $(html).filter(selector).get(0)
    return (check)? $(check) : false;
}
```