# How to get jquery to find href that is phone number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all callable phone numbers out of an html-received with a `get`:

```
onload: function (data)
{
    data = $.parseHTML(data.response);
    var content = $.trim($(data).find('[href^=callto:]').text());
    console.log(content)
    //var content= $(data).find('.');
}
```

The data is correct, i successfully found `find('.tel')`, a class used in the html.

Comment: Probably your links are at the top level of the `$.parseHTML` result array. Use `filter` instead of `find`. (If this is your problem, here's a very closely related question: [jQuery() not finding elements inside of results from jQuery.parseHTML()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403600/jquery-not-finding-elements-inside-of-results-from-jquery-parsehtml).)

Answer (score 8):

`$('a[href^="tel:"]')` will give you all anchors with a `tel:` scheme.

Using your sample code: `data.find('a[href^="tel:"]')`

Comment: that's not he problem, the html I'm using uses callto: forexample: view-source:http://personer.eniro.se/resultat/Erkan%20Salievski/216%2030%20LIMHAMN

Comment: So change it to `data.find('a[href^="callto:"]')`

Comment: FYI, `tel:` is the generic scheme for phone numbers. `callto:` seems to be a Skype thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to resolve this problem on my end. :)

```
/* All phone numbers to href */
var regex = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
$('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon is a special character in jQuery selectors. You should escape it like this: `$(data).find('[href^=callto\\:]')`