# jQuery replace certain characters in img title attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have an img title attribute that contains the following set of characters: `<h1>Image ABC</h1><p>There ist another paragraph</p>` (the html tags are neccessary to achieve a certain formatting as the title also serves as the caption of the image, this is a restriction of the CMS)

How can I remove certain characters in the img title attribute using jQuery (especially the html tags)? For example I want to remove everything in the title attribute except `Image ABC`

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: What decides what to keep? You can replace the parent container's content with the <h1></h1> if you wish

Comment: What do you want to get rid of - just all HTML tags and their content? And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried $("img").prop("title").replace("<h1>", ""); but doesn't work. But the example from @mplungjan worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the title attribute, try this

```js
$(function() {
  $("img[title^='<h1']").each(function() {
    var title = this.title;
    $(this).prop("title",title.substring(0,title.indexOf('</h1>')+5));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img title="<h1>This will stay</h1><p>This will go</p>" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-164-153-6.jpg" />
```

Or better (no need for parseHTML by the way, as long as we .append or .html it to a tag first)

```js
$(function() {
  $("img[title^='<h1']").each(function() {
    var $title = $('<div/>').html(this.title);
    $(this).prop("title",$title.find('h1').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img title="<h1>This will stay</h1><p>This will go</p>" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-164-153-6.jpg" />
```

If you meant an actual title you can do

```js
$(function() {
  $(".title").each(function() {
    $(this).html('<h1>'+$(this).find("h1").html()+'</h1>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title"><h1>Image ABC</h1><p>There ist another paragraph</p></div>
```

Comment: `op` is asking for `<img title="">` attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot @mplungjan. Your first approach was exactly what I needed. Did a small modification and now it gives me the desired output: `$(function() {
  $("img[title^='<h1']").each(function() {
    var title = this.title;
    $(this).prop("title",title.substring(4,title.indexOf('<\/h1>')));

  });
});`

Comment: See second example for the H1 content

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<img title="<h1>Image ABC</h1><p>There ist another paragraph</p>" src=""/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 var $img=$('img');
 var $t=$.parseHTML($img.attr('title'));
 // you need to append your title string to output element
 // source http://stackoverflow.com/a/15403888/1817690
 $img.attr('title',$('h1', $('<output>').append($t)).text());
```

```js
 var $img=$('img');
 var $t=$.parseHTML($img.attr('title'));
 $img.attr('title',$('h1', $('<output>').append($t)).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img title="<h1>Image ABC</h1><p>There ist another paragraph</p>" src=""/>
```

Comment: Clever. I have not seen parseHTML before. Is there an actual reason to use it?`$('<output>').append($img.prop("title"))` should get the same, no?

Comment: I would want to test that.

Comment: This worked for me without parseHTML:  `var $title = $('<div/>').html(this.title);`

Comment: But you need a `div element` now, you have to use that div to get `h1 text` which may affect the DOM and in my case I used a dummy element `output` which has only significance to get the `h1 element` from the title string without affecting DOM.

Comment: I fully expect `var $title = $('<dummy/>').html(this.title);` to work too

Answer (score -1):

You can replace some **specific words** with the replace function of Javascript:

```
var $data = "<h1>Image ABC</h1>";
$data.replace("ABC","");
```

Maybe if your tags dont have ids or *unique identifier* you cann use .each

```
$(function() {
  $(".title").each(function() {
    $(this).html('<h1>'+$(this).find("h1").html()+'</h1>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx, @Mike, for your idea. I went with the solution from mplungjan.