# jQuery find not working in top-level elements if not added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading some HTML with jQuery asynchronously:

```
$.get(path, {}, function (data) {
    var result = $(data);
    var resultSelector = result.find(selector);
});
```

`result` is a valid HTML *that contains* my selector (in my specific case, `"#UsersAndRolesResults"`).

I can see that it contains when I simply type `result` into the console, it's *there* exactly with the same ID, no typos or anything.

However, `result.find(selector)` returns 0 elements.

In my specific example, this is `result`:

[image]

And:

[image]

Why?

**UPDATE**: I can query for *other elements that are inside `#UsersAndRolesResults` with their ID tag and they are returned correctly*. I also *cannot* query any other top-level elements in the result. I think there is an issue with querying top-level elements inside the result.

**UPDATE 2:** Just try `$('<div id="target"></div>').find("#target")` and you will get 0 results, where you should obviously get the `div`.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, I think it's because the "result" is not yet part of the DOM. It hasn't been bound to anything.

Comment: @WonderGrub yes it's not added to DOM, and I *can't* add it to DOM as I need to grab only the element with that ID, and replace an element that already exists on the DOM with the same ID. I don't think it's a good idea to have two elements with the same ID simultaneously in the DOM.

Comment: Is `result` an entire `document`?

Comment: @guest271314 no, it's just part of a document

Comment: Can you reproduce at plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @guest271314 I've already solved the issue, see my answer

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu _"Just try `$('<div id="target"></div>').find("#target")` and you will get 0 results, where you should obviously get the div"_ ? `#target` would not be an expected result of `.find()` chained to `$('<div id="target"></div>')`. `.find()` searches for child elements of selector

Comment: `.find()` searches for child elements. Use `.filter()` for top level elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No. This is not bug, this is behavior defined in jQuery.**

`find()` is used to select the elements which are inside the element on which `find` is called. In your case, the element is not children of the selector, so `find` will not work.

Example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="message">Hello World!</div>
    <div>Bye World</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#container').find('.message');
```

This will select the element having class `message` and which is inside the element having ID `container`.

But, if you use `find`, it'll return nothing i.e. empty array since there is no element `#container` inside `#container`.

```
$('#container').find('#container');
```

Your code is equivalent to this ^^^.

---

If you want, you can use `filter`. `filter` will go through each element and check if this matches the selector, if it then the element is added to the result set.

```
$('#container').filter('#container');
```

This'll give you complete element.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `filter`. Great.

Comment: `.closest()` would return same result

Comment: @guest271314 NO. OP have a HTML code as string and want to get `top` level element like the example I've given.

Comment: @Tushar _"NO. OP have a HTML code as string and want to get top level element like the example I've given."_ Actually, OP has not included what `data` is at original Question. Yes, `.closest()` would traverse both current selector, that is string wrapped in call to `jQuery()`, and return jQuery object representing selector if parameter to `.closest()` is selector within string passed to `jQuery()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38035135/

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Can you add the HTML in question and do you always want to get top level element?

Comment: @Tushar Note, given image at Question, `data` would not be begin with `#container` or `#UsersAndRolesResults` element

Comment: @guest271314 The `container` was just an example and you can see the comma between elements.

Comment: The original description of `data`, image containing `#UsersAndRolesResults`  element where `.row` is first element in `data`, and later example `html`, `js` at OP _"Just try `$('<div id="target"></div>').find("#target")`"_ do not appear to match

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a design decision with jQuery. Top-level elements in an AJAX result are not queried correctly with `find`. Interesting.

I've solved my problem with a workaround by creating a dummy `div` element, encapsulating my result inside that element, and then querying that dummy element. It worked:

```
var t = $("<div>")
t.append(result);
t.find("#UsersAndRolesResults"); //this one returned my object correctly
```

For a simple example, try:

`$('<div id="target"></div>').find("#target");`

You will get 0 results.

Try:

`$('<div><div id="target"></div></div>').find("#target")`

And you'll get the correct result.

Comment: Interesting, in my reduced case I wrapped my 2x `<div />` elements in a parent container by default.

Comment: If I remove the wrapping element from the sample HTML data, I get 0 Nodes returned - a bug you have found.

Comment: _"It seems to be a bug with jQuery"_ Can you include  `html` string or array `data` at Answer? For ability to reproduce initially described issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `$('<div id="target"></div>').find("#target");` would not be expected to return `#target`; `.find()` searches for child elements

Comment: @guest271314 oh, then it's a design issue. anyway, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu It is not an issue, you can utilize methods which traverse both current selector and child elements. Still not certain what `data` is at original Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I can't paste the `data` itself directly for various reasons, but as I've posted in the screenshot, it's an HTML string (not a whole document) with some elements at the root level.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu _"I can't paste the data itself directly"_ You could create a representation of `data`, whether string or array, without pasting exact `data` or `html`. You could change tag names and `id`s, `className`s, while still conveying form of original `data`, without compromising any portion of  original `data`. How to reproduce the issue without representation of `html` which caused issue?

Comment: @guest271314 I've already did exactly what you said and demoed the issue as you an see at the end of my answer. It's actually simple and very similar to that one-liner at the end, and exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Image of `result` does not appear to be same as `<div id="target"></div>`. _"It's actually simple and very similar to that one-liner at the end,"_ Could you reproduce `data` as a text value, with `id`'s, tag names, `className`s changes as text, instead of image?

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't tell its the same, I've told that it's very similar. And by similar I'm not talking about the names etc, I'm talking about the structure. Does it really matter? I don't understand why you are insisting on me posting `data`? Isn't **an example that reproduces the exact same issue** enough?

Comment: The image at OP and example `html` later provided do not match; is not exact same as depicted at image. Why should viewers of Question ignore this?

Comment: @guest271314 No one said that they exactly match. in the answer, I've just posted an **example** and marked it as **a simple example** clearly, which would be more than enough for anyone who can simply think analytically, knows some javascript, reads the question, and understands the context.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get(path, {}, function (data) {
    var result = $($.parseHTML(data));
    var resultSelector = result.find(selector);
});
```

Comment: Nope, the result object is the same and still 0 results.

Comment: What is the real content of "path" ? I mean, in HTML.

Comment: I can't post the full HTML but it's exactly starting with what you see in the screenshot. Anyway, I've found the answer myself, see my answer.

Comment: I just reduced a test case and using this answer, I got the result you're after: http://imgur.com/BEi6W86  So I would qualify your input data.

Comment: @danjah and the contents of `data.html` is?

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem in the external html. Because I did a similar test and it works too.

Comment: @BrianSternari is, in your test case, the loaded HTML contains the selector as the top level element or not?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu `data.html` is `undefined`, however `result` looks fine with my sample HTML data, 2x `<div />` elements wrapped in another `<div />` element.

Comment: @danjah and what happens if the div you are looking for is directly a top-level element, and not the first one, e.g. your data.html is exactly like this (no wrapping <html>, <body> or anything): `<div id="first">test</div><div id="second">hello</div>` and you are looking for `#second`?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu yep, see my comment below :)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu. No. but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403600/jquery-not-finding-elements-inside-of-results-from-jquery-parsehtml

Answer (score 0):

Given

```js
console.log($("<div id=target></div>").find("#target"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`.length` would be `0` as expected.

---

You can use `.closest()` to search for both child elements and original jQuery object selector

```js
console.log($("<div id=target></div>").closest("#target"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wouldn't `filter` be a better option (I've just learned it from another answer)? as travesing up a tree with `closest` would feel a bit awkward; I'm already querying the top-level element and it wouldn't make sense to traverse up, but it does make sense to travese down.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu `.closest()` traverses current element; given `.find()` does not return expected result of query for an `id`, if element is in fact within `document`, could only be current selector or previous element within `document`

Comment: @Tushar _"Tried to run second snippet in console, got this VM823:211 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '<div id=target></div>' is not a valid selector."_ Does not return that result, here. Have noticed stacksnippets freezing following addition of `console`. Will create a plnkr

Comment: Yes, that works :). Only problem I see is that it'll return only one element when used with general selector e.g. class selector. As you can see in question there are two elements having `row` class. So, `$(thatHTMLString).closest('.row')` will return .... Whereas `filter` will return all the elements having `row` class. CC @CanPoyrazoğlu

Comment: @Tushar OP appeared to be traversing for single element having an `id`, not multiple elements. though, again, still not certain what `data` is at OP? Image depicted does not appear to match description _"result is a valid HTML that contains my selector (in my specific case, "#UsersAndRolesResults")."_ or example `"<div id=target></div>"`, where image at OP displays elements before `#UsersAndRolesResults`? `#UsersAndRolesResults` : data` would not be `<div id=UsersAndRolesResults></div>`